How do I split up multiple operations done on one line in C with Uncrustify?
In C, I want to split multiple operations done on one line to their own lines.
E.g.
int foo;
int bar;
foo = 123; bar = 456;

Should be changed to:
int foo;
int bar;
foo = 123;
bar = 456;

What Uncrustify configuration options can I use to achieve this?
I am using Uncrustify 0.72.0.

My solution was to set this setting to true:
# Whether to add a newline after semicolons, except in 'for' statements.
nl_after_semicolon              = true    # true/false

I also had to set this setting to true, otherwise it would mess up single-line cases:
# Whether to add a newline after a 'case' statement.
nl_after_case                   = true    # true/false

E.g. it would change:
case SOME_ENUMERATION: printf("Hello World!\n"); break;

To:
case SOME_ENUMERATION: printf("Hello World!\n");
    break;

And I also had to set this setting to true, otherwise it would mess up single-line if statements:
# Don't split one-line if/else statements, as in 'if(...) b++;'.
nl_if_leave_one_liners          = true    # true/false

E.g. it would change:
if (some_condition) { break; }

To:
if (some_condition) { break;
}


The first example should be rewritten to int foo = 123; int bar = 456; but that is beyond the capabilities of a code formatter.

@JonathanLeffler That depends. For local variables you typically want to initialize variables just before they are used and that's not always where they are declared.

@AugustKarlstrom: Since C99 you've been able to declare local variables where they're first used, so there's no real excuse not to initialize the variable in the definition.  There are places where an initializer isn't warranted, such as int x; if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) { … }.  But most of the time, they can be initialized and should be initialized.

I believe what you're talking about is more related to linting (because int foo; can be undefined behaviour). But my example is purely for formatting, not linting.
